# Drive unmounts and remounts intermittently

Tags: raspbian

I have a drive with media files. It's mounted on `/media/pi/media`. The drive unmounts and remounts intermittently. What is wrong?

It didn't behave like this a few days ago. But now it unmounts

- Every time I start transmission (downloading directly to disk)
- Every few minutes when a Plex client plays video off it
- As far as I can see, intermittently at other times

I have previously run `sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/pi/media/` and `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/pi/media/`. This is probably bad and might affect this issue, but I don't know.

Is there some fix I can try? Would a new disk solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe the usual: marginal power supply?

Comment: Good to know what kind of drive, and if it is the only one.

Comment: It was a power supply problem as @Dirk suggested. Unplugging some peripherals solved the problem.

Comment: Please make an answer for the solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish it. Otherwise it will pop up again and again for years (and for nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a power supply problem as @Dirk suggested. Unplugging some peripherals solved the problem